# How to resolve ImportError in Gurobi?

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to run this [example](http://www.gurobi.com/resources/examples/food-manufacture-I) given in gurobi's example model. I am using python 3.5 with gurobi 7.0.2. When I run the code, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gurobipy import *
  File "/if5/wua4nw/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gurobipy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .gurobipy import *
ImportError: libgurobi70.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have Gurobi installed at `/if5/wua4nw/gurobi702` and I can see the required file `libgurobi70.so` at `/if5/wua4nw/gurobi702/linux64/lib/libgurobi70.so`. I am using Anaconda3 by the way.

I have seen this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gurobi/ZnokECXffPM) but couldn't solve the problem yet. Can anyone shed some light so that I can solve the problem?

Comment: Did you check the [official docs](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/quickstart_linux/software_installation_guid.html)? It's actually quite easy to install. Maybe describe exactly what you did. (Linux?)

Comment: I'm confused: that looks like a mix of Windows and Linux. Are you using Bash on Windows? That isn't a supported configuration: you should use Gurobi for Windows.

Comment: @sascha thanks, I have solved my problem. I didn't include the required 3 lines in my `.bashrc` file, that's why I was facing the error! @Greg I have updated my post to avoid confusion, I am using linux.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I didn't notice the instructions in the [official docs](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/quickstart_linux/software_installation_guid.html). Thanks to @[sascha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2320035/sascha).

> Users of the bash shell should add the following lines to their `.bashrc` files:

```
export GUROBI_HOME="/opt/gurobi702/linux64" 
export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin" 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/lib"
```

I followed the instructions and it solved my problem.

Comment: Adjusting `.bashrc` didn't suffice for me. I had to adjust `.profile`, too.

Comment: Note to others: replace 702 (=version 7.0.2) to your own version number. For a more permanent effect, edit `etc/environment`

Answer (score 2):

This problem [from .gurobipy import] is caused from the IDE Pycharm on Ubuntu. I am not sure if you may face it with the other IDEs . 
First You can make sure from the shell the python has gurobipy installed. 
after you installed from the file Gurobi ~\gurobi752\win64.

```
python setup.py install
```

And add the libraries to the paths from the shell  `gedit ~/.bashrc`. Then just run python from the shell as normal python command 
`python yourFileName.py` and gurobi will works perfectly

In windows 10 i added the path of gurobi to the IDE pycharm
after `python setup.py install` and pip tool for gurobipy https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/python/pip-for-windows, then i added the path 
Settings->Project Interpreter-> show all -> interpreter paths -> add your gurobi path

I hope it works cheers ;)